# DropDownList with multiple columns per row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

Is there a plugin or any other way to make a dropdownlist with multiple columns of data for each row?

I want to show and select the project number, but I want to also show the name, city, state, start date and end date in the dropdown.

It's not hierarchical and not a combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made it a scrollable grid with a select button on each row.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to create columns in a dropdownlist but you can however add text as display name for an item, just concatenate a string with the info you want.

EDIT: i see that I obviously misunderstood your question, a simple way of doing it would be to create a div within this div have a header with the overview info and then a paragraph which is hidden by default and  then use jquery `.slideToggle()` function.

Comment: I was just hoping for something "prettier" than a concatenated string.

Comment: @RememberME if you are using a <select><option></option></select> then you can't, however with jquery or javascript in general you can make regular html simulate the feel of it and make it look the way you desire, shouldn't be too difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would look in to the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ASPNET/ajax_logo.png), specifically the [DropDown Sample](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/dropdown/dropdown.aspx).

You can bind the dropdown to show any control, giving you a lot more themeing flexibility.

Other option is to create a custom control that inherits the dropdownlist and modify its rendering method (but this would most likely be a great deal of work).

Comment: He is using MVC, not Webforms.